# Mock Unit Testing - Getting details of the classes implementing interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a User Interface lets call it `IUser`. 
There are two implementations of this: `AdminUser and NormalUser`.

Now, I am trying to use these user classes via Unit Testing(Mocking).

I mock the interface as follows:

```
var mockUser = new Mock<IUser>();

mockUser.get("username");
```

I have added breakkpoints throughout the classes but I am not sure which instance of the interface is getting called i.e `AdminUser or NormalUser`.

It never stops at the debug points and no clue from the mockUser instance.

**How can I get the details of the class being called by the mockUser mock instance?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: neither one is being called. Moq creates its own implementation proxy with the interface and allows you to configure the behavior. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to test  the implementations or a subject that depends on them?

Comment: Hi Nkosi, Yes, I am trying to test the individual implementations of the interface. Any clue how can I do that? 
BTW, thank you for letting me know about XY problem :)

Comment: In order to test the actual implementations then you need to initialize the actual implementations i.e. `new AdminUser()`. If either of the implementations have external dependencies then you would mock those (the dependencies) and inject them. If a class depended on an `IUser` and you wanted to test that class then you would have a reason to mock `IUser` for an isolated unit test.

Comment: If you want to text individual classes then you don't need to use mock and interface. Just create direct instance of class and call method on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a `Mock<IUser>` actually creates a *new* implementation of `IUser`. So it won't help you to test any of your actual implementations.

Using a `Mock` works something like this:

Suppose I have this class and interface. The class validates whether a postal code is valid for a country. It depends on another interface which provides the regex pattern for the given country.

```
public class PostalCodeValidator
{
    private readonly IPostalCodeRegexProvider _regexProvider;

    public PostalCodeValidator(IPostalCodeRegexProvider regexProvider)
    {
        _regexProvider = regexProvider;
    }

    public bool ValidatePostalCode(string postalCode, string countryCode)
    {
        var regex = _regexProvider.GetPostalCodeRegex(countryCode);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(regex)) return true;
        return Regex.IsMatch(postalCode, regex);
    }
}

public interface IPostalCodeRegexProvider
{
    string GetPostalCodeRegex(string countryCode);
}
```

The implementation of `IPostalCodeRegexProvider` could be anything. It could call a database, it could be hard-coded.

But when I write unit tests for `PostalCodeValidator`, I explicitly *don't* want to test a real implementation of `IPostalCodeRegexProvider`. I want to make `IPostalCodeValidator` return exactly what I want so that I can make sure that `PostalCodeValidator` works. I'm only testing `PostalCodeValidator`.

If I want to test that `ValidatePostalCode` returns `true` when `IPostalCodeRegexProvider.GetPostalCode` returns null, then I need to make sure that it *will* return null. That's where the `Mock` comes in.

It allows me to easily create an implementation of `IPostalCodeRegexProvider` that will always return null, so I can test what `ValidatePostalCode` does with that null.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ValidatePostalCode_ReturnsTrueWhenRegexIsNull()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IPostalCodeRegexProvider>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.GetPostalCodeRegex(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(default(string));
    var subject = new PostalCodeValidator(mock.Object);
    Assert.IsTrue(subject.ValidatePostalCode("xyz","abc"));
}
```

Whatever the subject of the test is - in this case `PostalCodeValidator`, or in your case `AdminUser` and `NormalUser` - that's what you would create an instance of. If those classes depend on other interfaces then you might create a `Mock` for each of those interfaces.

You can also consider using a "test double." Instead of using Moq, you just create a simple class that implements the interface. For example, what I did with Moq I could also do like this:

```
public class PostalCodeRegexProviderThatReturnsNull : IPostalCodeRegexProvider
{
    public string GetPostalCodeRegex(string countryCode)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the unit test would look like this:

```
public void ValidatePostalCode_ReturnsTrueWhenRegexIsNull()
{
    var regexProvider = new PostalCodeRegexProviderThatReturnsNull();
    var subject = new PostalCodeValidator(regexProvider);
    Assert.IsTrue(subject.ValidatePostalCode("xyz","abc"));
}
```

That is often easier to understand than using a `Mock`. Sometimes the setup for mocks can get complicated and difficult to read and debug, but a simple class can do the job just as well or even better.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test the actual implementations then you need to initialize the actual implementations i.e. `new AdminUser()`.

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAdminUser {
    //Arrange
    IUser admin = new AdminUser();
    //...set any necessary members relevant to the test

    //Act
    //...invoke member to be tested

    //Assert
    //...verify actual to expected behavior

}
```

If either of the implementations have external dependencies then you would mock those (the dependencies) and inject them.

If a class depended on an `IUser`

```
public class SomeClass {
    private readonly IUser user;

    public SomeClass(IUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    //...
}
```

and you wanted to test that class then you would have a reason to mock `IUser` for an isolated unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomeClass {
    //Arrange
    var username = "dummy";
    var expected = "some value";
    var mock = new Mock<IUser>();
    //...set any necessary members relevant to the test
    mock.Setup(_ => _.username).Returns(username);

    var subject = new SomeClass(mock.Object);

    //Act
    //...invoke member to be tested
    var actual = subject.SomeMethod();

    //Assert
    //...verify actual to expected behavior
    Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use Moq